# How Can I Assign Multiple Values To A Void

Tags: c#

How Can I Assign Multiple Values To Where It Says uint i need to to be from 0 to 18 because im doing something client based a it needs to be done for all 18 clients at once

```
RPC.doTypeWriter((uint) 0 , (int)numericUpDown21.Value, metroTextBox22.Text, (short)numericUpDown23.Value, (double)numericUpDown24.Value, (float)numericUpDown25.Value, (float)numericUpDown26.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown35.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown36.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown37.Value, (int)numericUpDown27.Value, (int)numericUpDown28.Value, (int)numericUpDown29.Value, (int)numericUpDown30.Value, (int)numericUpDown31.Value, (int)numericUpDown32.Value, (int)numericUpDown33.Value, (int)numericUpDown34.Value);
```

Comment: Huh? You can't assign **any** values to a void, and a uint can only have one value at a time. If you want to transfer multiple values at once, an array or list may serve. Otherwise: maybe call the method multiple times (depending on context)

Comment: ive tried calling it multiple times but it seems to glitch it out

Answer (score 1):

You can't. An `uint` is a single integer value, it can't hold multiple values.

Use a loop to loop from 0 to 17 (as that is 18 clients):

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  RPC.doTypeWriter(i, (int)numericUpDown21.Value, metroTextBox22.Text, (short)numericUpDown23.Value, (double)numericUpDown24.Value, (float)numericUpDown25.Value, (float)numericUpDown26.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown35.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown36.Value, (ushort)numericUpDown37.Value, (int)numericUpDown27.Value, (int)numericUpDown28.Value, (int)numericUpDown29.Value, (int)numericUpDown30.Value, (int)numericUpDown31.Value, (int)numericUpDown32.Value, (int)numericUpDown33.Value, (int)numericUpDown34.Value);
}
```

The naming suggests that you are doing RPC calls to the clients, so you might need to move more code into the loop, e.g. doing the connection to each client in the loop.

Comment: Thanks you if i sounded dumb im sorry only just started

Comment: @AdamHeapsiMoD1998: I don't think that it's dumb, it's a completely logical solution except for the fact that it's impossible. Keep thinking outside the box. :)

Comment: thanks dude might be a late reply ive got it fully working thank you so much for understanding